# VBA - Code for pivot table won't generate table

Tags: vba, pivot-table

This is my first time trying to write a VBA code that generates a pivot table. The following is my code, when I run it I don't get any errors and the new worksheet is generated but not a pivot table in sight.

Thanks!

```
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("WorkCat PT").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "WorkCat PT"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set PSheet = Worksheets("WorkCat PT")
DSheet = ActiveSheet.Data

LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)

Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=DSheet.Cells(2, 16), TableName:="WorkCatPivotTable")

With ActiveSheet.PTable.PivotFields("Work Category")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
End With

With ActiveSheet.PTable.PivotFields("Total Cost")
.Orientation = xlColumnField
.Position = 1
End With

With ActiveSheet.PTable.PivotFields("Total Cost")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 1
.Function = xlSum
.NumberFormat = "$ #,##0"
.Name = "Work Category"
End With
```

Comment: Can't say I'm surprised you don't get any errors when you start your subroutine with `On Error Resume Next`... Remove that and try running again :)

Comment: Oops, that explains that one! Thank you!

Comment: So what line is throwing the error?

Comment: One of the heading names was off by a space, the first With line should have been "Work Category " not "Work Category".